# Error installing Datatables on Laravel 6.0.4

Tags: laravel

I have installed a fresh copy of Laravel using command
"composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel Project"

After running migration I am trying to install Yajra Datatables.
Used following command as mentioned on website :
"composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:^9.0"

Following error is displayed after initial setup :

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - laravel/passport 6.0.x-dev requires illuminate/http ~5.6 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - laravel/passport v6.0.0 requires illuminate/http ~5.6 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - laravel/passport v6.0.1 requires illuminate/http ~5.6 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - laravel/passport v6.0.2 requires illuminate/http ~5.6 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - laravel/passport v6.0.3 requires illuminate/http ~5.6 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - laravel/passport v6.0.4 requires illuminate/http ~5.6 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - laravel/passport v6.0.5 requires illuminate/http ~5.6 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - laravel/passport v6.0.6 requires illuminate/http ~5.6 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - laravel/passport v6.0.7 requires illuminate/http ~5.6 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - don't install illuminate/http 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.33|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.34|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.35|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v6.0.4, required as ^6.0) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.0.4].
    - Installation request for laravel/passport ~6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/passport[6.0.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.0.5, v6.0.6, v6.0.7].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

What I am doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: `laravel/passport 6.0.x-dev requires illuminate/http ~5.6` doesn't look like this is datatables related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems support for Laravel 6.x was only added since [version 9.6](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/commit/7ae86cf380c31f5479ae4f3e71164b8254393451).

So try running:

```
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:^9.6
```

---

Or even better, just omit the version so composer can find the best version for your project.

```
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle
```